# Java program that monitors system date and sends email automatically

Tags: java

I'm working on a system that does a bunch of stuff, as well as monitors the current date on a system, checks it against a stored date in a database, and if both dates are exactly the same, sends an email automatically to a bunch of users.

Now, I've been able to do everything else (the email sending, reading data from the database, you name it), except the monitoring part. What technique do I employ such that once the program is running, and the user is using the program, some part of that program is also carrying out checks on system date and the date stored in the database?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the checks supposed to run periodically or at user input time?

Comment: `if both dates are exactly the same` - at what precision? Note that Java dates have millisecond precision and if you are only 1 millisecond off (which might happen due to things like garbage collections etc., even if you check the date every millisecond) the dates won't be _exactly_ equal.

Comment: Erik, no this is not a home work. I'm designing a software for a client and I thought this would be a cool feature.

Comment: Thomas, it doesn't have to be millisecond precise, so long as the date is the same, be it in the morning or afternoon, an email should be sent - once, of course. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using scheduler (Quartz or cron), or start a thread at target time, I'd recommend you to use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` to check periodically.

Advantages against other approaches: 1. it will reflect latest DB change at the moment. 2. it is easier to implemnt. 3. the logic can be reused or unit tested

Comment: Glad that you have tried. It will help if you can upvote my answer, LOL.

Comment: sorry, forgot about the upvoting thing. Very new to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your check to run periodically (for example, once per day), use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`, or some kind of scheduler library like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Each check would involve making a query against the database to check if the emails need to be sent.

See this article for more information, and examples: http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the target-date from the database, calculate the time from now to the target-time and start a thread that sleeps for the calculated time and triggers your main-program again, when the sleep-time (target-time) is reached.

This will work when no changes to the target-time (in the database) are expected.

Otherwise you have to check your database periodically and reset your sleeping-thread if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mailScheduler` for this re fer this
http://www.oop-reserch.com/scheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless the timing of the email sending is critical, you could just add a cron job to start the check every hour or so, rather than continously run.

In terms of the check itself, you could store the values in the DB using the to string method in [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), and when you perform the check revert the string to a Date using the String constructor and compare.